# Render QR Code from item id using separate view and component file

Tags: vue.js, qr-code

I have a view file and a QR component. I need to render the QR code in my component based on the id I pass from the parent view.

Scan.vue template:

```
<template>
  <div p-0 m-0>
    <div class="scanBreadcrumbs">
      <h2 v-show="path">{{ path.join("/") }}</h2>
      <h2 v-if="path.length === 0">Show location</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <div v-if="item.HasChildren === true">
          <div class="locationBox" @click="swapComponent(item)">
            {{ item.Name }}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
          <v-expansion-panel>
            <v-expansion-panel-content>
              <template v-slot:header>
                <div>{{ item.Name }}</div>
              </template>
              <v-card>
                <QR :value="item.Id"></QR>
              </v-card>
            </v-expansion-panel-content>
          </v-expansion-panel>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div v-if="path.length > 0">
        <div class="backButton">
          <v-icon @click="swapPrevious()" class="arrow">fa-arrow-left</v-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

QR.vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas ref="barcode"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import QRCode from "qrcode";
export default {
  name: "QR",
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },

  methods: {
    async render() {
      console.log("barcode");
      try {
        await QRCode.toCanvas(this.$refs.barcode, this.value, {
          errorCorrectionLevel: "H",
          width: 300,
          value() {
            this.render();
          }
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      } finally {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

No QR code is being rendered and I'm not sure why. Weird thing is I can render it using a dialog with Vuetify but if I want to render it in an expansion panel nothing show up.

Comment: Where are you calling the method `render` for the first time? I believe you are missing an async `mounted` hook where you should await your `render` method. `async mounted() { await this.render() }`

Comment: I think that did the trick. Wasn't sure if I needed a computed or mounted. Thank you very much.